# Откуда может браться прибавление пробела к результату в IBDataSet

Tags: sql, firebird, компоненты

В *IBDataSet* в «SelectSQL», прописан запрос:

```
select * from (select CHIPHER_ETALON as NAME, ID, 'GOV_ETALON' as TABLE_NAME from GOV_ETALON  
where DATE_EXPIRATION < '24.12.2015'  
union all  
select NAME, ID, 'REGISTER_ETALON' as TABLE_NAME from REGISTER_ETALON 
where DATE_EXPIRATION < '24.12.2015') order by NAME
```

В результате выполнения в строках *DBGrid*, в которых поле «TABLE_NAME» равно «GOV_ETALON», после *GOV_ETALON*, **еще берется откуда-то 5 пробелов**? Откуда пробелы берутся, понятия не имею?…
А там, где «TABLE_NAME» равно «REGISTER_ETALON», - все нормально.
В IBExpert, результат, без проблем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird преобразует строковые константы в char(maxlength), то же касается любых конкатенаций. IBExpert обрезает концевые пробелы. См. IB Expert - Регистрационная информация базы - Дополнительные - "Обрезать концевые пробелы полей типа CHAR".

Замените `select *` на `select NAME, ID, cast(TABLE_NAME as varchar(50))`.

**UPD** Да, простого `cast`'а недостаточно. Поможет `trim`, вы верно предположили:

```
select NAME, ID, cast(trim(TABLE_NAME) as varchar(50))
from
(select CHIPHER_ETALON as NAME, ID, 'GOV_ETALON' as TABLE_NAME from GOV_ETALON  
where DATE_EXPIRATION < '24.12.2015'  
union all  
select NAME, ID, 'REGISTER_ETALON' from REGISTER_ETALON 
where DATE_EXPIRATION < '24.12.2015') order by NAME
```

Comment: Не, чего то не получается, *select NAME, ID, cast(TABLE_NAME as varchar(50)) from (select CHIPHER_ETALON as NAME, ID, 'GOV_ETALON' as TABLE_NAME from GOV_ETALON
               where DATE_EXPIRATION < '24.12.2015' union all select NAME, ID, 'REGISTER_ETALON' as TABLE_NAME
                  from REGISTER_ETALON where DATE_EXPIRATION < '24.12.2015') order by NAME*. даже в IBExpert (если предварительно снять указанную Вами галку),

Comment: Это обрезается до 50 знаков результат, хотя максимум там 15 знаков - это "*REGISTER_ETALON*"., так что общий результат урезать до10 не получится

Comment: функция '**TRIM**', помогает, хотя только в *IBExprt*, в *Dataset* - пока не очень. **Например** *select * from (select CHIPHER_ETALON as NAME, ID, trim('GOV_ETALON') as TABLE_NAME from GOV_ETALON  where DATE_EXPIRATION < '26.12.2015' union all select NAME, ID, 'REGISTER_ETALON' as TABLE_NAME  from REGISTER_ETALON where DATE_EXPIRATION < '26.12.2015') order by NAME*. В *Dataset*  **отображается также с 5-ю пробелами**

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да, еще раз спасибо. В *DataSet* - строка с обрезанными пробелами, но зато "*DBGrid*", продолжает издеваться - т.е. показывает пробелы

Comment: Пришлось заменить DBGrid, и все нормализовалось :-), Так и не понятно, причем тут, *DBGrid* к лишним пробелам?